# Python: offset data by 30 days

Tags: python, pandas, date, datetime, datetimeoffset

I have a DataFrame like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(index=pd.date_range(start='2022-01-01', end='2022-05-01', periods=100))
df:
2022-01-01 00:00:00.000000000
2022-01-02 05:05:27.272727272
...
2022-04-29 18:54:32.727272728
2022-05-01 00:00:00.000000000
```

I want to offset the data by 30 days so the data should look like this:

```
df:
2022-02-01 00:00:00.000000000
2022-02-02 05:05:27.272727272
...
2022-04-29 18:54:32.727272728
2022-05-01 00:00:00.000000000
```

I tried `df.index.DateOffset(days=30)` but I get an error `AttributeError: 'DatetimeIndex' object has no attribute 'DateOffset'`

Any recommendations on how to do that?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: adding 30 days to `2022-01-01` gives `2022-01-31` not `2022-02-01`, which one do you want?

Comment: @d.b Thanks for the quick reply. I was a little confused with what the Offset endpoint does.

Comment: @mozway Sorry, I wanted the `2022-01-31` result. I miss calculated

Comment: Then you can run `df.index+=pd.DateOffset(days=30)` for in place modification ;)

Comment: Thanks for the reply and clarification on how to use the Offset endpoint :)